# openlayers drupal missing site building module

Tags: drupal, openlayers

I don't have http://xxx/**admin/build/openlayers/layers/** in my Acquia-drupal installation acquia-drupal-win-1.2.30-5322.19124

Is there anything I can do to have the openlayers inside the Site-building section of drupal ?

currently I can only configure stuffs in **http://xxx/admin/settings/openlayers** (site configuration). Does this have something to do with Acquia version of drupal ?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the layers submodule under admin->build->module

Comment: did you mean the 'OpenLayers Layers' submodule ? It is enabled, and I am still having this problem

Comment: If this is the case, then there could be a menu issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Drupal 7 if you're using the Acquia stack, in which case probably should look at the [Drupal 7 OpenLayers Guide](http://drupal.org/node/1481374)

Might also want to move the conversation over to https://gis.stackexchange.com/